# how do I count and print out the total number of zeros after the decimal places?

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a way to count and display the total of numbers of an string, but I don't know how to go by doing that. here's the example:

```
65.0-43.0+21.0= 43.0
 65 -43 +21 = 43 
 65.0 -43.0 +21.0 = 43.0 
 65 - 43 + 21 = 43 
 65.00 - 43.0 + 21.000 = +0043.0000
```

the output needs to give me:

```
Digit: 20 0
```

*that's the total number of zeros I have in this example. Not just the zeros after the decimals. If somebody can point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: this looks like a job for regular expressions

Comment: Write a loop, iterate through the string for its length, use charAt to get each character, compare to "0", count matches.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some pseudo-code to do what you want:

```
zeroCount = 0
state = notAfterPoint

for each character c
  if c == '.'
    state = afterPoint
  else if c is not a digit
    state = notAfterPoint
  else if state == afterPoint and c == '0'
    zeroCount++

print zeroCount
```

I'll leave converting this to Java code to you.

Comment: +1 for not using a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

To count digits in a string:

```
int digitCount = str.replaceAll("\\D+", "").length();
```

To count 0s in a string after decimal point:

```
int zeroCount = str.replaceAll("^[^.]*\\.", "").replaceAll("[^0]+", "").length();
```

Or in single call count 0s in a string after decimal point:

```
int zeroCount = str.replaceAll("(?>^[^.]*\\.|[^0]+)", "").length()
```

**EDIT:** To count all 0s

```
int zeroCount = str.replaceAll("[^0]+", "").length();
```

Comment: He wants only zeros *after* `.`.

Comment: @arshajii: May be I am not reading question correct but OP says: **`that's the total number of zeros`**

Comment: _how do I count and print out the total number of zeros after the decimal places?_

Comment: @anubhava but there are 20 `0`s in the op's sample, but 18 after the `.`

Comment: Alright thanks for these comment, I will edit it

Comment: Sorry for misreading the question earlier, edited now.

Comment: Sorry guys. The correct answer was 20 zeros. my TA corrected the project to make it flow easier for us.

Comment: In that case my original answer should work: `str.replaceAll("[^0]+", "").length();`